# Java To C#: How to create a simple message transfer / connection?

Tags: java, c#, http, communication

I need to talk to a simple C# application (run as a sub process) to gain easy access to some Windows stuff (writing a Java to Windows layer is doable but would take to long and would not be have tested well).

The idea is now to expose the C# capabilities using a http (or a rpc version) server and talk to this server from the java side.

Is there a good and simple root to take. I am a Java pro but C# I can barely read (same with the other guys).

So if there is a simple framework to talk to both sides it would be very good.

Comment: This sample may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/12901839/932418

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple web service (I use WCF) and register various methods to perform any action you like.